# How to create a Key Vault managed storage account?

Tags: azure, key, command-line-interface, storage, vault

I'm brand new to Azure and am trying to create a KV managed storage account. I've created a resource group, an ADLS account and a Key Vault. I've tried running these commands:

```
az role assignment create --role "Storage Account Key Operator Service Role" --assignee "https://vault.azure.net" --scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<StorageAccountResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/**myADLSaccName**"

az keyvault storage add --vault-name **myKVname** -n **myADLSaccName** --active-key-name key1 --auto-regenerate-key --regeneration-period P30D --resource-id "/subscriptions/**mySubscriptionID**/resourceGroups/Sab_RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/**myADLSaccName**"
```

The first one runs fine, the second one keeps giving me this error:

*'storage' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
Did you mean 'restore' ?*

Comment: Hey organza, as per this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys, did you run the command for  "Give your user account permission to managed storage accounts"?

Comment: Hi Yash, yes I've just done, and it keeps giving me the same error. I can't get past this step for some reason, it keeps saying 'storage' is misspelled or not recognized by the system. Did you mean 'restore' ?

Comment: Can you pls share a screenshot with the command and the error?

Comment: Hi, the other poster shared this command, which finally worked. Thanks very much for replying anyway!

$regenerationPeriod = [System.Timespan]::FromDays(90)
Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName '<your-vault-name>' -AccountName '<your-storage-account-name>' -AccountResourceId '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxx' -ActiveKeyName 'key1' -RegenerationPeriod $regenerationPeriod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *storage' is misspelled or not recognized by the system. Did you mean 'restore' ?*

Initially, I followed the same document and I got the same error in my environment like same as above.

As of now, the **`az keyvault storage`** command is not available in the **`Azure CLI`** commands.

I checked with the below command:

```
az keyvault --help
```

In the above command, there is no **`storage`** subgroup  as of now:

[image]

Alternatively, If you need to create a KV-managed storage account. you can use the **`PowerShell`** command:

**Command:**

```
$regenerationPeriod = [System.Timespan]::FromDays(90)
Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName '<your-vault-name>' -AccountName '<your-storage-account-name>' -AccountResourceId '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxx' -ActiveKeyName 'key1' -RegenerationPeriod $regenerationPeriod
```

The above command equals the same command as **`az keyavult storage add`** sets up an existing Azure Storage Account with Key Vault for Storage Account keys to be managed by Key Vault.

**Output:**

```
Id                  : https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net:443/storage/venkat098
Vault Name          : xxxx
AccountName         : xxxx
Account Resource Id : /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/vxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxx
Active Key Name     : key1
Auto Regenerate Key : True
Regeneration Period : 90.00:00:00
Enabled             : True
Created             : 11/15/2023 5:51:26 AM
Updated             : 11/15/2023 5:51:26 AM
Tags                :
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount (Az.KeyVault) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/add-azkeyvaultmanagedstorageaccount?view=azps-10.4.1)

Comment: Oh wow, you're an absolute hero. I honestly spent several hours trying to figure this out, and that worked flawlessly! Thank you so much!!